# Running .bat file from TeamCity

Tags: batch-file, teamcity

How can I automate executing a batch file from TeamCity. Can I create a TC build configuration and have the TC agent build that and automatically run the specified batch file?

EDIT: batch script.

```
echo off

echo Do you want to deploy xxxx to DerServ(yn): 
set /p input=

if "%input%" == "y" goto :1
if NOT "%input%" == "y" goto :2

:1
SET MSBUILD="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe"
%MSBUILD% xxxxx.defaultTeamCity.msbuild /target:projBuild

goto end
 :2
ECHO Exiting...
goto end
 :end   

 pause
```

Error message:

> [12:25:12]: 'projBuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,[12:25:12]: operable program or batch file.[12:25:13]: Build finished

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using [Command Line runner](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Command+Line).

[image: Build Step]

Comment: How about using MSbuild runner option?

Comment: You can use any configuration that can run other batch or executable files, Ant, MSbuild, etc, but if you want just to run one bat file, you should use the most simple and appropriate configuration as suggested in my answer.

Comment: :I tried doing this by command line option.. but I am getting an error.. please see original post edits. Thanks for your help

Comment: In the buildstep I picked the following options: Runnertype :Commandline ; Run: Custom Script ; Custom script : I put the contents of the script .bat file. I have just one build step defined.

Comment: Found solution to this issue. Its with incorrect relative path in the batch file. Thanks for your input

Comment: Could anyone provide a sample usage please?